# Resolution difficulties in Grass

Tags: raster, grass-gis, resolution

I have gone through similar questions to mine here, but I didn't find a solution. Please help!

When cropping a raster image by using `g.region` & `r.mapcalc`, I get a new image but the resulting  image doesn't have the same resolution. I have used `r.resample` in the outer raster map but is still different. I have tried to change the resolution using `g.region`, and even though the resolution is the same, the image display is not.

Is there a way in grass to cut an image from the main raster image and keep the resolution unchanged?

Also, I have tried using zoom to choose the crop area and its works! but as I have to do the same with a lot of images and need to be precise (when zooming), so it is difficult and takes a lot of time.

How could I solve this? Many thanks!

Comment: That's very unlikely. each mapset has a fixed resolution based on g.region. Im sorry for questing you bad have you checked the resulting image's resolution with r.info just to be sure?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm re-checking the procedure I was following...

Comment: Please also see http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region

Comment: Ok. I'm doing right with resolution now. Maybe I was not following the instruction in the right order before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need simply `g.region` twice, first to set the resolution to the same as the original raster, and a second time to change the extents, so:

```
g.region rast=<original_raster>
g.region e=... w=... n=... s=...
r.mapcalc clipped_rast=original_rast
```

You can also permanently set the MAPSET region with g.region -s res=... e=... w=...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Takes me a while to conceptualize the concepts. So far everything is working following the steps here.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to crop a raster is to create a mask for the area you want to extract, either from a raster of from a vector and then (with the mask raster present) run:

`mapcalc "mImage_Croped = mImage"`

Comment: Thanks. I 'm comparing the result of cropping by creating a mask and using g.region. I think with the last one I would use less memory as have to work with severals images.